# Running Python Code on XAMPP Localhost Server

Tags: php, python, apache, server, xampp

I am trying to run a python app, on a localhost server, on XAMPP. 
The code is a very basic one, in order to see if I can run it on localhost. 
The php code runs, but the python code returns me with an error.
The error message will be shown below.

I tried a very simple php code that worked and also a very simple python code, that didn't worked.
I made the addition of .py and index.html in the XAMPP files, but it still doesn't work.

I mention I am using Python 3.7.3

The error message received when I try to run the python script:

Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

**Error message:**

> couldn't create child process: 720002: test.py
>
> ```
> >     If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
> >     Error 500
> >     localhost
> >     Apache/2.4.39 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2r PHP/7.1.29
> ```

Comment: Does XAMPP generally deal with Python out of the box? Possibly config issue? Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: I don't think it deals Python out of the box, but adding the .py and index.html terms in httpd.conf text file should let XAMPP manage python too.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP isn't really gonna help you. XAMPP is meant for PHP primarily. You can use the apache in the XAMPP stack though.

Look at:

- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-run-python-scripts-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-18-04/
- https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/use-uwsgi-to-deploy-python-apps-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04/